# Permissions for file in Linux can't be changed by user of owner's group

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, ownership

I created a directory and placed a file in it from `user1`. Permissions for this file and directory is `070` for example. Then I created `user2` and added him to `user1 group`. I try to use `chmod 000 /home/user1/directory/file` by `user2` and see "*action not permitted*" or "*permission denied*". Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a file/directory owner or root can use chmod/chgrp/chown on a file/directory.  That is just how it is designed to work.

Giving the group rwx permission allows group members full access to the contents of the file but not the metadata which holds the owner/group/permission information for the file.

Comment: Thank you! Are there any other differences between permissions to owner and to his group? Or this is the exclusive exception?

Comment: Permissions-wise, it works the same whether owner or group as long as correct permissions are set.  Owner/mode is metadata and not the same as permissions (i.e. rwx).

Comment: Sorry, what are owner/group bits? I know, that permissions are incoded in bits, i know suid and sticky bit, but i can't find an information about bit of user/group, only about uid/gid.

Comment: Don't take _bits_ literally.  I changed that wording.  Check out information regarding UNIX [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) to see what I mean in regards to _metadata_.